# Clicking on the Delete button in navigator to delete offline data

Tags: jqgrid

I just tried deleting a few selected rows by clicking on the Delete button in the navigator of a grid, but I got a warning message in the confirmation popup saying that the url is not set. I am wondering if the navigator supports deleting offline data without setting a url.

Maybe I can override the default delete function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by overriding the built-in delfunc of the navigator.

```
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', 
{
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:true,
    delfunc: function (rowids) {
        if (rowids && rowids.length > 0)
        {
            rowids.sort();
            for (var i=rowids.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                deleteRow(rowids[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```